# Conditional joint CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, conditional-probability

Is this the definition of conditional probability of 2 continuous random variables conditioned on 1 continuous random variable? **Please provide a reference**.

(I forgot if any 2 continuous random variables necessarily have a well-defined joint pdf.)

Instead of the usual $$P(z_1 < Z < z_2 | B=b) := \int_{z_1}^{z_2} f_{Z|B=b}(z) dz,$$ with $f_{Z|B=b}(z):=\frac{f_{Z,B}(z,b)}{f_B(b)},$ it looks like we'll have like $$P(z_1 < Z < z_2, u_1 < U < u_2 | B=b) := \int_{u_1}^{u_2} \int_{z_1}^{z_2} f_{(Z,U)|B=b}(z,u) dz du,$$ with $f_{(Z,U)|B=b}(z,u) := $, I think, $\frac{f_{Z,U,B}(z,b,u)}{f_B(b)}$

- Note: if any of the definitions ':=' are in fact *not* definitions, then you'll have to explain conditioning on an event of probability zero to me please.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence#Conditional_independence_of_random_variables) just says for 'conditional cumulative distribution function' or conditional CDF of $X$ and $Y$ on $Z=z$ is $F_{(X,Y)|Z=z}(x,y):=P(X \le x, Y \le y|Z=z)$, but it doesn't quite define $P(X \le x, Y \le y|Z=z)$.

- For just 1 continuous random variable conditioned on 1 continuous random variable, it's $P(X \le x, |Z=z) := \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_{X|Z=z}(t) dt$, where $f_{X|Z=z}(t) := \frac{f_{(X,Z)}(x,z)}{f_{Z}(z)}$.
- For 2 continuous random variables conditioned on 1 continuous random variable, I think it's $P(X \le x, Y \le y|Z=z) := \int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} f_{(X,Y)|Z=z}(t,u) du dt$, but then...
- What's $f_{(X,Y)|Z=z}(t,u)$? (I guess we do the elementary probability way of thinking: define the pdf before the cdf...) According to [this site](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_3_0_chapter_problems.php) (see problems 1 and 16), it's $f_{(X,Y)|Z=z}(t,u): = \frac{f_{(X,Y,Z)}(t,u,z)}{f_Z(z)}$. So, I guess I'm right about joint cdf/pdf stuff. I'm just hoping for a reference please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joint CDF of 2 Unif(0,1) that are based on 3 other Unif(0,1)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066689/joint-cdf-of-2-unif0-1-that-are-based-on-3-other-unif0-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in Larsen and Marx

> [image]

- unfortunately this is for discrete. it seems there's no mention of a continuous BUT THEN there's an exercise THAT ASSUMES a definition for continuous.

Also found in

Walpole, Myers, Myers and Ye

> [image]

- I believe it applies for both continuous and discrete.