# How do I compute the distribution of $\min\{X,Y,1-Y,1-X$ $,|X-Y|,1-|X-Y|\}$, where $X,Y \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, mathematical-modeling, uniform-distribution

Let $X,Y \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$. Let $$M = \min\{X,Y,1-Y,1-X,|X-Y|,1-|X-Y|\}.$$ Supposedly $\operatorname{image}(M) \subseteq (0,\frac13)$ and distribution of $M$ is $$F_M(m)= (3m(2-3m))1_{(0,\frac13)}(m) + 1_{(\frac13,\infty)}(m).$$ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058750/most-random-points-on-a-circle).

**Question**: How do I compute the distribution of $M$? I wonder if there's a clever way of doing this like with $W$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058726/more-random-points-on-a-circle). Below is what I've tried so far.

Well $|X-Y| \ge m$ and $1-|X-Y| \ge m$ tell me $m \le |X-Y| \le 1-m$. So it looks like I have 4 cases

1. $x+(m-1) \le y \le x-m$
2. $x+m \le y$
3. $y \le x-m$
4. $x-(m-1) \le y \le x+m$ (but I think I rule out this last case because here I have $m \ge \frac12$.

Then $X,Y,1-Y,1-X \ge m$ tell me $m \le X \le 1-m$ and $m \le Y \le 1-m$. So I guess the 3 cases become

1. $x+m-1 = \max\{m,x+m-1\} \le y \le \min\{x-m,1-m\} = x-m$
2. $x+m = \max\{m,x+m\} \le y \le 1-m$
3. $m \le y \le \min\{x-m,1-m\} = x-m$

But it seems if I do $\int_0^1 \int_{\cdot}^{\cdot} 1\, dy \,dx$ for each case and then add them up I get only $2-6m$.

Comment: It might help to draw the unut square, divided into regions where each of the options is the minimum, then draw level curves for $M$

Comment: You can break this into two steps: let Z = min(X, Y, |X-Y|).  Then min(Z,  1-Z) is the six-way minimum you're looking for.

Comment: @Empy2 Thanks! ok tried something like that on wolfram...

Comment: @MichaelLugo thanks but what's the difference? Are $Z$ and $1-Z$ independent? Are $\min\{X,Y\}$ and $|X-Y|$ independent? It looks like I'll just end up doing the region anyway.

Comment: @Empy2 posted answer. please let me know what you think.

Comment: @MichaelLugo posted answer. please let me know what you think.

Comment: @MichaelLugo That doesn't work because $\min(1-X,1-Y,1-|X-Y|) = 1 - \max(X,Y,|X-Y|)$...

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks for pointing that out! I think this still works but you have to use a  more complicated symmetry than the obvious one.

Comment: Also asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/514285/119261.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $m\in[0,1]$,

\begin{align}
F_M(m)&=1-\mathbb{P}\{M>m\} \\
&= 1-\mathbb{P}\{X\in (m,1],Y\in (m,1],1-Y\in (m,1],1-X\in (m,1],\\
&\hspace{7cm}|X-Y|\in (m,1],1-|X-Y|\in (m,1]\}\\
\\
&= 1- \mathbb{P}\{X\in(m,1-m),Y\in(m,1-m),|X-Y|\in(m,1-m)\}\\
\\
&= 1- \mathbb{P}\{X\in(m,1-m),Y\in(m,1-m),X-Y\in(m,1-m),X\geq Y\}\\
&\hspace{2cm}- \mathbb{P}\{X\in(m,1-m),Y\in(m,1-m),Y-X\in(m,1-m),X < Y\}\\
\\
&=  1-2\mathbb{P}\{X\in(m,1-m),Y\in(m,1-m),X-Y\in(m,1-m),X\geq Y\}\\
\\
&=  1-\begin{cases}
2\mathbb{P}\{Y\in(m,1-2m),X\in(m+Y,1-m)\} & \text{ if } m<1-2m \\
0 & \text{ if } m\geq 1-2m
\end{cases}\\
\\
&= \begin{cases}
1-2\int_{y=m}^{1-2m}\int_{x=m+y}^{1-m} 1\cdot dxdy=6m-9m^2  & \text{ if } 0\leq m<1/3 \\
1 & \text{ if } m\geq 1/3.
\end{cases}\\
&= 3m(2-3m)\mathbb{1}_{\left(0,\frac13\right)}(m) + \mathbb{1}_{\left(\frac13,\infty\right)}(m).
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

As a function of $X$ and $Y$, $M$ has the following symmetries:

$$
\begin{align}
M(X,Y)&=M(Y,X), \\
M(X,Y)&=M(1-X,1-Y), \\
M(X,Y)&=M(|X-Y|,\max(X,Y)).
\end{align}
$$

Being the minimum of piecewise-linear functions, its graph is piecewise-linear (the symmetries can help understand this graph):

[image]

Alternatively, here is the corresponding contour plot:

[image]

Having found the maximum of $M$ to be $1/3$, we can see that the survival function, $P(M(X,Y)>m)$ is obtained by integrating over 2 congruent right triangles in the uniform $(X,Y)$ space.

Note that the length of a leg of one of these triangles, $l(m)$, satisfies
$$l(0)=1, \\l(1/3)=0. $$  Linear interpolation then gives

$$l(m)=1-3m, $$
and thus
$$P(M(X,Y)>m) = (1-3m)^2. $$

Finally, the CDF is

$$1-(1-3m)^2 , 0 \leq m \leq 1/3.$$

Comment: thanks! actually, i posted an answer. is my answer correct please?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how defining $H$ is relevant, so I'm going to ignore that part of your question.

We start by observing that if $$M(X,Y) = \min\{X, Y, 1-Y, 1-X, |X-Y|, 1 - |X-Y|\},$$ then $$M(X,Y) = M(Y,X),$$ so we can restrict our attention to the case $0 \le Y \le X \le 1.$, which describes a triangular domain on the unit square.  Then on this domain,  $$M(X,Y) = \min\{Y, 1-X, X-Y\}.$$  This is because:

- We can eliminate $X$ since $X \ge Y$.
- We can eliminate $1-Y$ because $1-Y \ge 1-X$.
- $|X-Y| = X-Y$ since $X \ge Y$.
- $1-|X-Y| = 1-X+Y \ge 1-X$, so we can eliminate this also.

Consequently, the probability $$\Pr[M > m \mid 0 \le Y \le X \le 1] \\ = \Pr[(Y > m) \cap (1-X > m) \cap (X-Y > m) \mid 0 \le Y \le X \le 1], \tag{1}$$ since in order for $M > m$, each of $Y, 1-X, X-Y$ must exceed $m$; conversely, if each of $Y, 1-X, X-Y$ exceed $m$, then $M > m$.  But the simultaneous inequalities on the RHS of $(1)$ can be interpreted as the region of the $(X,Y)$-plane comprising the interior of an isosceles triangle with vertices at $$(2m,m), (1-m, m), (1-m, 1-2m).$$  The first vertex comes from combining the first and last inequality:  $Y > m$ and $X - Y > m$ implies $X > m + Y > 2m$.  The second vertex is direct from the first and second inequalities.  And the third vertex comes from the second and third inequalities:  $X < 1-m$ and $Y < X-m$ implies $Y < 1-2m$.  So, remembering the symmetry about $X = Y$, the desired probability is equal to twice the area of this triangle, namely $$\Pr[M > m] = \begin{cases} 1, & m < 0 \\ (1 - 3m)^2, & 0 \le m \le 1/3 \\ 0, & m > 1/3. \end{cases} $$ hence $$f_M(m) = 6(1-3m) \mathbb 1(0 \le m \le 1/3).$$

Comment: thanks! i removed the $H$. actually, i posted an answer. is my answer correct please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's what I did on wolfram:

By trying out values of $m=\frac15, \frac16, \frac17$ (Btw: $\frac14$ was kind of an outlier. **See below** re 'only issue'. Also, as expected, $\frac13$ gave no solutions), I got 4 cases

1. $x \in (m,2m)$, $y \in (x+m,1-m)$
2. $x \in (2m,1-2m)$, $y \in (m, x-m)$
3. $x \in (2m,1-2m)$, $y \in (x+m, 1-m)$
4. $x \in (1-2m,1-m)$, $y \in (m,x-m)$

When sketching this, I ended up getting 4 trapezoid figures.

Anyhoo, I got

1. $\int_m^{2m} \int_{x+m}^{1-m} 1 dy dx$
2. $\int_{2m}^{1-2m} \int_{m}^{x-m} 1 dy dx$
3. $\int_{2m}^{1-2m} \int_{x+m}^{1-m} 1 dy dx$
4. $\int_{1-2m}^{1-m} \int_{m}^{x-m} 1 dy dx$
5. Combining (1) and (3), we get $\int_m^{1-2m} \int_{x+m}^{1-m} 1 dy dx$
6. Combining (2) and (4), we get $\int_{2m}^{1-m} \int_{x+m}^{1-m} 1 dy dx$
7. Combining (5) and (6) we get our desired distribution.

**My one issue however** is the very fact that we say $(2m,1-2m)$ in the first place suggests $m \in (0,\frac14)$ only! (**See above** re 'outlier'.) I mean, I don't think $2m$ and $1-2m$ should be compared, but I think $m$ and $1-m$ should be compared.

I think this can be fixed if we just do 2 cases

1. $x \in (m,1-2m)$, $y \in (x+m,1-m)$, combining (1) and (3)
2. $x \in (2m,1-m)$, $y \in (m, x-m)$, combining (2) and (4)

Comment: How did you get the 4 cases?

Comment: @Explorer i just guessed by trying it out on wolfram with $m=\frac15, \frac16, \frac17$